# How to send push notifications to others in iOS and android when I click the send button

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

My scenario is I have selected particular contact from my Phone after that 
I shared an amount with the selected contacts , and I click the send button. when I clicked the send button that selected contacts want to get the notification with the amount. can anyway say how to implement this path.

**sending Push notifications using FCm**

> *My Appdelegate file*

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications 

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {  

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self as! MessagingDelegate
        //Register for notification
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }
    // [END receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    // This function is added here only for debugging purposes, and can be removed if swizzling is enabled.
    // If swizzling is disabled then this function must be implemented so that the APNs token can be paired to
    // the FCM registration token.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")

        // With swizzling disabled you must set the APNs token here.
        // Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        completionHandler([])
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler()
    }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didRefreshRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

> **ViewContoller.swift**

```
import UIKit

import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func Notify(_ sender: Any) {
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")

    }
}
```

Comment: server is taking care of that so i believe your question needs to be much more specific. You don't know how to implement push in your app? there was multiple questions about that on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

```
First you need to implement FCM-Google Platform / APN- Setup own server and backend with the same. Scenario Like, 
    1. Implement FCM/APN 
    2. Implement back-end, design database structure 
    3. App needs to communicate with server using Web service
    4. Share your contact with server (I guess you have implement login functionality with contact number)
    5. Generate token for your unique user. Your all contact must have install app in device with relevant contact number. Push notification worked on Token. So,generate token for all user. 
    6. Other things taken care by the server (back-end)


Reference URL:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client
https://www.appcoda.com/firebase-push-notifications/
https://pushtry.com/fcmtutorial.aspx
```

Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need an own server and / or Google Firebase Cloud Messaging

Please refer to [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for more information

Comment: Iam using the FCM but I am not understanding how the path to be followed for that scenario

Comment: Please edit your question and show a minimal example of what you already tried https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve